Why does my iOS app crash when defining a SwiftData model with a Set?
Background
I am learning to use SwiftData while working to upgrade my existing SwiftUI app's storage.
In one of my main data models, I have been using a Set for its guarantee that stored objects are distinct. After adding the @Model annotation, I am finding that my app now crashes on launch with the following error:
Error
Thread 1: Fatal error: Failed to link relationship to destination entity 'Set because it could not be found in the model: (<NSRelationshipDescription: 0x60000330cc80>), name eggs, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity Bird, renamingIdentifier eggs, validation predicates (
), warnings (
), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {
}, destination entity (null), inverseRelationship (null), minCount 0, maxCount 1, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 2

Alternatively, Arrays work
When I modify the model to store the data as an Array rather than a Set, it launches, runs, and saves/recalls data as expected. However, Arrays are unsuitable for my use case.
Code Excerpts
I have created a sample project on GitHub, so you can easily get started with my demo project. You can clone it here: https://github.com/fraune/SwiftDataSetDemo

Bird holds a nest of unique Eggs.
@Model
class Bird {
    var id: UUID
    var species: String
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var eggs = Set<Egg>() // CASE 1: Fails
//  @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var eggs = [Egg]()    // CASE 2: Works

    ...
}


Egg must conform to Codable to be used in a Set.
Hashable wasn't strictly required, but it didn't seem to make a difference for this problem. I wanted it to be clear that only an Egg's id can be used to differentiate two Eggs.
@Model
class Egg: Codable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var ageWeeks: UInt

    ...

    static func == (lhs: Egg, rhs: Egg) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }

    ...
}

Final thoughts and my question
Presumably I have a misunderstanding of how to use SwiftData, or there's something going on behind the scenes that I don't understand.
Can you help fix my code and explain what was wrong with it? Bonus points if you can provide a relevant link to official SwiftData documentation about this issue.

I have seen it mentioned in articles that using Array for a to-many relationship is a requirement but I have no link to any official documentation stating so, personnaly I have just accepted that it's an Array type you use for this and moved on. Your last headline is "Final thoughts and my question" but you never stated a clear question but my guess is you want some hard evidence that only Array can be used or...?

Yeah, you're right I didn't really ask a question there haha. But yes I was just looking for hard evidence. I would like to understand where I should have found that using a Set like this was incompatible (if it definitely is).
